# Why does this Grand Central Dispatch code doesn't work?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

It's my first Grand Central Dispatch code but it doesn't work. Working on Mac OS X 10.8 and last Xcode version. I know it's too basic. Thanks.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <dispatch/dispatch.h>

void printResult(int r);

void printResult(int r)
{
    NSLog(@"%i", r);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            int number = pow(2, 5);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                printResult(number);
            });
        });
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First. Your application actually exits *before* the blocks you passed in GCD could finish.

To fix that, you could use GCD **groups** and synchronization tools that they give you.

```
@autoreleasepool {
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);
    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
        int number = pow(2, 5);
        dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            printResult(number);
        });
    });

    dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
}
return 0;
```

Second. Here you will encounter another problem called **deadlock**. The Second block is added to the main thread queue. And main thread is actually *waiting* for this block to finish, so it could not be executed. Add the second block to the queue you've created before.

```
dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
    printResult(number);
});
```

Now you can see `32` in console, which is what you expect.

Comment: In a GUI program, you *would* want to use the main queue to update the UI, and you would be able to do that because you *wouldn't* be exiting immediately after doing work.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myQueue", NULL);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            int number = pow(2, 5);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                printResult(number);
            });
        });
    }
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run]; 
    return 0;
}
```

I think you just need a runloop here.